# How do I know if a runway has REIL?

Tags: airport-lighting

I'm designing an airport of a flight simulator. One of the runway settings is [Runway End Identifier Lights](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runway_end_identifier_lights) (REIL). Is there a way I can see if a runway at a US airport has [REIL](https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/ato/service_units/techops/navservices/lsg/reil/) via the internet, and whether they are Omnidirectional or Unidirectional REIL?

Comment: If the runway has other runway lights, it typically would have REILs. If the runway has an instrument approach, it typically has MIRL or HIRL and the REILs.

Comment: @Ksisky I am not aware of any database where you could find information on whether a REIL installation is Omni- or Uni-directional. The only way I know of is to go and see for yourself what they actually are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find this information in the Airport Facility Directory which is published in print by the FAA and is available [for free from them online here](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/digital_products/dafd/search/). REIL will be listed for the specific runway for the airport in question. For example I fly out of KDYL and if we take a look at the page in the AFD for KDYL you will see REIL listed for RWY 23

[image] 
([source](http://aeronav.faa.gov/afd/04feb2016/ne_259_04FEB2016.pdf))